# Static NSArray of strings - how/where to initialize in a View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, initialization, nsarray

In a Master-Detail app I'd like to display a TableView with 5 sections titled:

1. Your Move
2. Their Move
3. Won Games
4. Lost Games
5. Options

So I create a blank Master-Detail app in Xcode 5.0.2 and then in its MasterViewController.m (which is a UITableViewController) I'm trying to implement the method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _titles[section];
}
```

**My question** is however how to init the NSArray _titles?

I'm trying in the MasterViewController.m:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

static NSArray *_titles_1 = @[
    @"Your Move",
    @"Their Move",
    @"Won Games",
    @"Lost Games",
    @"Options"
];

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_games;

    NSArray *_titles_2 = @[
                         @"Your Move",
                         @"Their Move",
                         @"Won Games",
                         @"Lost Games",
                         @"Options"
    ];
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     ....
}
```

but both tries above give me syntax errors:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

To my surprise there are many suggestions for this simple question, but as an iOS/Objective-C newbie I'm not sure, which solution is most appropriate.

`dispatch_once` - isn't it a runtime operation to execute something once in a multi-threaded app? Isn't it overkill here? I was expecting a compile-time solution for initiating a const array...

`viewDidLoad` - when my app changes between background and foreground, wouldn't it unnecessary initiate my const array again and again?

Shouldn't I better set the `NSArray` in `awakeFromNib` (since I use stroyboard scenes for all my ViewControllers)? Or maybe in `initSomething` (is the correct method `initWithStyle`?)

Comment: Init it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You should change the signature to `static NSArray* const` instead. There are many ways to solve when to initialize the array as seen in the answer below. I like lazy inits, but it isn't really suited for this use case.

Comment: What you're looking for is a (choke!) singleton-style initialization.  It does not need to be in its own class, however, it can be a part of this class.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber iOS apps are multi-threaded, and class methods can be called concurrently by multiple threads, so it's safer to use `dispatch_once` or some form of locking. I can tell you from first-hand experience that otherwise the potential for crasher bugs is very real.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Write a class method that returns the array.

```
+ (NSArray *)titles
{
    static NSArray *_titles;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _titles = @[@"Your Move",
                    @"Their Move",
                    @"Won Games",
                    @"Lost Games",
                    @"Options"];
    });
    return _titles;
}
```

Then you can access it wherever needed like so:

```
NSArray *titles = [[self class] titles];
```

Comment: The user is asking WHERE to create this, not how. You haven't provided any help, the users answer shows him trying to instantiate an object in an interface

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Quoting the OP, "My question is however **how** to init the NSArray _titles?" [emphasis added]

Comment: @jlehr and if you read the rest of the question you will see he is getting syntax warnings due to the above mentioned issue. The user is asking for a basic understanding of how to instantiate an object in the flow of a viewController object. Fair point your solution might be the best way to create it, but the user is quite clearly looking for info as to WHERE to create it

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be a runtime solution (instead of the compile-time that I was expecting) - is it the best choice for iOS?

Comment: Objects can't be allocated at compile time, so this is typically what we do. Note that `dispatch_once` is a Grand Central Dispatch function that ensures the code in the provided block is only run once in the lifetime of the app.

Comment: You can use the fully qualified class name to call the static method.  Instead of [[self class] titles] you can just call [MyClassName titles];

Comment: @BrodyRobertson Targeting a specific instead of obtaining a reference to the class dynamically class breaks inheritance. Also, not sure what you mean by 'fully qualified' class name -- Objective-C doesn't provide namespaces for classes. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @jlehr a fully qualified name is an unambiguous name that specifies which object, function, or variable a call refers to without regard to the context of the call.  I don't understand what you mean when you say calling a static method via it's qualified classname breaks inheritance.

Comment: Objective-C class methods are not static -- they're dynamically dispatched exactly the same way instance methods are, are inherited, and can be overridden in subclasses.

Answer (score 12):

You can init it in class method [+initialize](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize)

```
static NSArray *_titles_1;

@implementation MasterViewController
+ (void)initialize {
    _titles_1 = @[
        @"Your Move",
        @"Their Move",
        @"Won Games",
        @"Lost Games",
        @"Options"
    ];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've search and it seems (surprisingly!) that this method can be called more than once for a class - when an inheriting class does not implement own *+initialize* method.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Then check that _titles_1 is nil or for the current class in `+initialize`

Comment: If I check for `nil` - can't it happen that the `+initialize` method runs once, but for a wrong class - for the inheriting class?

Comment: +initialize runs once for the class itself, and once for every subclass that doesn't override it. That's why you compare "if (self == [MyIntendedClass class])" first. The check for nil makes it necessary to use synchronisation because two subclasses could be initialised from different threads.

Comment: @gnasher729 `+initialize` is thread safe, according Apple documentation : `The runtime sends the initialize message to classes in a thread-safe manner.`

Answer (score 8):

You should declare your static array above  `@implementation`.

```
static NSArray *titles_1 = nil;

@implementation ...
```

And define it in `init` or `awakeFromNib` or any other method like `viewDidLoad`, `applicationDidFinishLaunching` wherever you want.

```
- (void)initMethod{ //change the method name accordingly

    if (titles_1 == nil){
        [self setTitles_1:@[ @"Your Move", @"Their Move", @"Won Games", @"Lost Games", @"Options" ]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also do something like this:

```
static NSString * const strings[] = {
        [0] = @"string_1",
        [1] = @"string_2",
        [2] = @"string_3",
        [3] = @"string_4",
        // ...
    };
```

It's not an `NSArray` but you can access `NSStrings` like this `strings[n]`

Comment: Sometimes, most always the simplest solution is not only the most effective, but the best... Being relatively new to Obj-C (7 years now) I'm still put off by the syntax, but I was pretty sure, a simple static array didn't need to involve 25 lines of code.. My C/C++ background told me this would probably work... NSString *dayNamesArray[7] = {@"blah",@"blah",@"blah",@"blah",@"blah",@"blah",@"and blah"}; I give you credit for the most common sense solution... Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I wonder, if the following would be a good way (answering my own question):

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

static const NSArray *_titles;

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
    NSMutableArray *_yourMove;
    NSMutableArray *_theirMove;
    NSMutableArray *_wonGames;
    NSMutableArray *_lostGames;
    NSMutableArray *_options;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

+ (void)initialize
{
    // do not run for derived classes
    if (self != [MasterViewController class])
        return;

    _titles = @[
        @"Your Move",
        @"Their Move",
        @"Won Games",
        @"Lost Games",
        @"Options"
    ];
}
```

This way the `const NSArray` is initalized once and right before I need it (in the `MasterViewController` class). And the `self` check prevents this method from running again - when some inheriting class does not implement its own `+initialize` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can't instantiate objects in this way, you can only declare them in interfaces. Do the following:

```
static NSArray *_titles_2;

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_games;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad()
{
     _titles_2 = @[
                         @"Your Move",
                         @"Their Move",
                         @"Won Games",
                         @"Lost Games",
                         @"Options"
    ];
}
@end
```

- or likewise you could use the viewcontroller init method instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: That would mean every instance would have its own copy of the array. I don't think that's what the OP was looking for.

Comment: fair enough, the point still stands that he's trying to instantiate the object in the interface, this would remove his xcode complier warnings, ill edit with a static array

Comment: If you look carefully, you'll see that the OP posted two different failed attempts, the first of which was an attempt to initialize a global constant with an `NSArray`.

Comment: @jlehr - How many instances of this view controller do you think there are going to be?

Comment: @HotLicks no that was a valid point, the user did clearly define a static array. The user more than likely had a reason for going out of there way to do that

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin - Can you say "premature optimization"?

Comment: If I use *viewDidLoad*, then the *_titles* will be assigned again and again, when I press Home button to send the app to background and then bring it to foreground?

Answer (score 2):

dispatch_once works. It works in complicated cases, and it works in simple cases. So to be consistent, the best thing is to use it in all cases. That makes it for example a lot easier when you replace all your constant strings with calls to NSLocalizedString (). No code change needed.

Doing things in + (void)initialize isn't really wrong, but I have had situations where I first wanted to configure a class before really using it, and initialize is of course called just before any possible configuration method would start executing. And there are situations where you don't really have a class context. dispatch_once will always work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use :

```
+(NSString*)titleForSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return (@[ @"title1", @"title2", @"title3" ])[section];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use Objective-C++,change filename from `xxx.m` to `xxx.mm`,and the initialize of NSArray will happen at runtime

**no** `dispatch_once`,**no** class method,just write it in one line:

```
static NSArray *const a = @[@"a",@"b",@"c"];
```

Comment: with that code you get the error: "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant"