# Objective C - Static class variable of type NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, static, nsarray

I'm storing some default initializer values for my class as static class variables. Like this:

```
// List.h
static NSString *DEFAULT_LIST_NAME = @"Not Set";
static BOOL DEFAULT_RECURSION = NO;
```

I also need a static variable of type `NSArray *` set to an empty array. How can this be achieved? Currently I get the error:

> Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Comment: Hi
This question is similar to yours. There are different ways to do that.
Maybe you want to check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544616/static-nsarray-of-strings-how-where-to-initialize-in-a-view-controller

Comment: @SamB Why would I want to do so?

Comment: show a screenshot of your error. I don't get any compile warnings or errors in my Xcode 8 if I use static code lines above

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the compile time error `"Initializer element is not a compile-time constant"` because the static variable's value is actually written into your executable file at compile time. So you can only use the constant values (not alloc/init which are executed at runtime). You can use any of the below option

1. You can write `static NSArray *arr = nil` and use `+initialize` to create your array.
2. Another options are you can use `__attribute__ ((constructor))`
3. Yet another option is to switch the type of your source file from Objective-C to Objective-C++ (or rename it from .m to .mm, which has the same effect). In C++, such initializers don't need to be compile-time constant values, and the original code would work just fine
4. Also you can use solution given Pat_Morita

Answer (score 0):

define a class method for this:

.m file

```
@implementation test
static NSArray *array; 
+ (NSArray *)array { 
    if (!array) array = [[NSArray alloc] init]; 
    return array;
 } 
@end
```